# Bash ignores vi-ins/cmd-mode-string options in .inputrc

Tags: bash, inputrc

When I first created my .inputrc (it didn't exist by default), I set `vi-ins-mode-string` to "+" and `vi-cmd-mode-string` to ":" to differentiate between modes. I didn't have "(cmd)" or "(ins)" prepended to my prompt by default, but later decided I did want those to show up instead, so I changed those options in my .inputrc. However, the "+" and ":" continue to be prepended to my bash prompt and I don't know why. I've tried sourcing .inputrc with `source` and `bind`, I've exited all instances of my terminal, but nothing works. Is there something I'm doing wrong here? My .inputrc is currently:

```
set show-mode-in-prompt on
set vi-ins-mode-string "(ins)"
set vi-cmd-mode-string "(cmd)"
```

**Edit:** when starting python's interactive cli from inside a virtual environment (created with conda, if that's important), the (ins) and (cmd) get appended appropriately. It's only on my regular bash commandline that the "+" and ":" continue to show up.

Comment: I had the exact same problem. Maybe you are not running bash 4.4 with readline 7.0. bash --version returned version 4.4 for me, however my start up shell (/etc/passwd) pointed to /bin/bash (4.3) instead of /usr/local/bin/bash (4.4). (typing 'bash' into the command line might show the string, given the bash version in your path is 4.4). BASH_VERSION holds the actualy current version of the bash shell currently running. If so, changing the start up shell in /etc/passwd to a bash binary version 4.4 might fix it.

Comment: I just ran `bash --version` and got back 4.3.48 (and some extra notation), so maybe that's it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add those lines to your `~/.inputrc` file.
2. Restart the shell (open a new terminal session).
3. Make sure that your `bash` shell is in `vi` command line mode with `set -o vi`.

Alternatively:

1. Add those lines to your `~/.inputrc` file.
2. Make `bash` reread the file using <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd> (you will have to switch to `emacs` mode temporarily for this first, with `set -o emacs`).
3. Make sure that your `bash` shell is in `vi` command line mode with `set -o vi`.

If you have an `INPUTRC` environment variable, then this will point to the file that is *actually* used.  Remove the variable from your shell's startup files (and restart the shell), or make sure that it has the default value of `$HOME/.inputrc` (and restart the shell).

Comment: I tried all of the above, but the prompt still doesn't change.

Comment: @alyms108 Do you have a colorized prompt? It's conceivable that the control characters in the `PS1` variable may interfere. Also confirm that you are in fact running `bash` (and not e.g. `zsh`), and that you have no `INPUTRC` variable set.

Comment: I am running bash and INPUTRC isn't set, meaning it might be the control characters for my colorized prompt. I have no idea how that would interfere/why it would keep changes to the prompt string from being noticed.